# Set Title Margin Android ActionBar programatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, margin, title

Is there anyway to margin ActionBar title programatically? My context is:

I use my main Activity with NoActionBar theme. So i use a toolbar as Actionbar. I have many fragments using as different screen in Main Activity. I want to margin some of fragment title.

[image]

Thank in advance.

Comment: u want margin between  homesreen icon and Activity name???

Comment: I just edited my post. My purpose is arranging the title and the content straightly

Comment: ohk u means action bar name and the contact list name in straight ???

Comment: I mean the action bar name. In some context, I got a imageview in very first of list item. So i have to margin left 104dp instead of 72 dp. I want the action bar name go by this way too.
(i design for tablet)

Answer (score 2):

There are some rules  for accuracy of designing ...
they are define as belove with image..

### 1. your image view

margin of image view from left edge is always 16

### 2.your textview

margin of your textview  from left edge is always 72

Thats why all our android application should work properly...and at least  same lookup...

please follow this link for material designing....[Link](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) 
hope it help a lots...

[image]

Comment: I got it. But i design for tablet. In some context, i have to margin left 104dp instead of 72 dp. I want the action bar name go by this way too.